# using boto to scan dynamodb table

Tags: python, boto, amazon-dynamodb

Folks,
  I have an 'admins' table, with 'UserName' as its HashKey.
  The table looks like this:

```
admins = Table('admins')
admins.put_item(data={
  'UserName':'jon',
  'password':'pass1',
  })
admins.put_item(data={
  'UserName':'tom',
  'password':'pass2',
  })
```

So to pull the users out, I am trying to do the following, but failing:

```
admins = Table('admins')
all_admins = admins.scan()
for x in all_admins:
  print x['UserName']
```

Why am I getting an empty set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing looks correct.

Have you confirmed the data actually got written?(take a look at the AWS console)
Are you trying to read directly after writing? The default read is eventually consistent, and thus you may not find items directly after writing them

Answer (score 0):

Use `Item=` instead of `data=` to insert the items, you can also use [batch](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/dynamodb.html)

```
admins = Table('admins')
admins.put_item(Item={
               'UserName':'jon',
               'password':'pass1'})
admins.put_item(Item={
               'UserName':'tom',
               'password':'pass2'})
```

And to pull the users you should use

```
admins = Table('admins')
all_admins = admins.scan(
             ConsistentRead=True)
items = all_admins['Items']
for x in items:
  print x['UserName']
```

This should do the job